# Route is not loading correctly in angular12?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an `angular12` app in which i have following routes

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     component: AppLayoutComponent,
     canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     children: [
        {path: 'configuration', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/configuration/configuration.module').then(m => m.ConfigurationModule)}
     ]
        },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
 ];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in my `configuration` module i have

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: ConfigurationComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ConfigurationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     CommonModule,
     RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class ConfigurationModule { }
```

I have my auth guard like this

```
 canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

  if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') != null) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    this.routes.navigate([RoutesContants.formRoutes.config]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

inside login.component.ts i have

```
loginApp(){
  localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/configuration');
}
```

When i run the app so it first loads `/login` route and screen which is perfect. When i click on `login` `button` so it should redirect me to the `/configuration` component which is in different `layout`. But it only refreshing the page not redirecting me to that `/configuration` `route`.

Comment: Do you see errors in the webbrowser console?

Comment: when i hit "Login" button so only page refreshes every time i hit login button and no errors on console